# CSS typographic issues (align left )

Tags: html, css

How should I increase the spacing between the three buttons and align them to the left?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could try to set some `margin` after and before each item => `margin:auto 3%`
To align them to the left you can use `float:left;` but it might doesn't work, it depends on the code

Answer (score 0):

Styles to parent `display : flex` , `justify-item : flex-end` and use `margin` for spacing buttons

```css
.foo{
display : flex;
justify-items: flex-end;
height : 200px;
width : 100px;
background-color: red;
padding : 10px
}

.bar{
height : 50px;
width : 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">

<div class="bar"> </div>
</div>
```